# Div with :before and :after content not responsive

Tags: css

I have a header that needs to have a greeting div inside of it. And that div has to be styled with :before and :after. I cannot add it via HTML. But when you resize the window, everything gets messed up. And I have no idea how to stop it from happening, without changing the font-size.

Can someone please take a look and tell me if there's something I can do? Thank you!

```css
.header {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1300/800/');
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 765px;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  padding: 0px 20px 7px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: 2px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .375);
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

.title:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f051";
  font-size: 1.5em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.title:after {
  content: "Hello hello";
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  top: 15px;
  left: 75px;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="title">
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try this code, removed the absolute position :

```css
.header {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1300/800/');
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 765px;
  text-align:center;
}

.title {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top:15%;
  padding: 0px 20px 7px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: 2px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .375);
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

.title:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f051";
  font-size: 1.5em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.title:after {
  content: "Hello hello";
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  top: 15px;
  left: 75px;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="title">
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
```